# SQL add asterisk to column values based on condition

Tags: sql, filter, case

I am using the tutorial database from [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc)
I need to add an asterisk to the ProductName column if ShipperID is 2

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, (Products.Price*OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalValue, Orders.OrderDate
FROM ((OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
WHERE OrderDetails.ProductID IN (19,20,21,68)
AND Orders.OrderDate <= #12/31/1996#;
```

In the link to test the queries, the `CASE` operator doesn't work on that link as I need something like this `CASE Orders.ShipperID = 2 THEN Products.ProductName + '*' ELSE Products.ProductName`

The following error results:

> An unspecified error occurred.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please do not use "doesn't seem to work", but share the complete error message to make it more clear what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell what you're trying to achieve with those pound symbols (`#`) around the date, so I removed that clause. But here's how to use a `CASE` statement, and append strings with `||` in SQL, which I think is where you're stuck:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Orders.ShipperId = 2 THEN Products.ProductName || '*'
  ELSE Products.ProductName
  end as PRODNAME,
(Products.Price*OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalValue, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.ShipperID
FROM ((OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
WHERE OrderDetails.ProductID IN (19,20,21,68);
```

Note that it's `Orders.ShipperID`, not `Orders.SupplierID`, which is what you were attempting to use in your `CASE` statement.

You could also do the append slightly differently like this:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName ||
  CASE
    WHEN Orders.ShipperId = 2 THEN  '*'
    ELSE ''
  END as PRODNAME ...
```

Also, you don't need as many parentheses as you're using, but I left them in. If you don't have a reason for them (personal style?), I suggest eliminating them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran that query and it resulted in an error. It doesn't seem like CASE works there. Is there another way of doing this besides CASE?

Comment: I clicked the link you embedded into your question and did a copy/paste of my answer. It works. Perhaps you're doing something different?

Comment: huh weird. I copy/pasted your query and it didn't work for some reason, I'm not sure what I could have done differently

Comment: it actually worked on this link https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_case2, but not in the one I embedded into the question. It seems like it works with MySQL

Comment: Yeah, your question really should specify-- with a tag-- which RDBMS you're targeting.

Comment: It turns out that this is SQLite, since CASE in unsupported, the correct operator is IIF

Comment: Again.... why you should have indicated in your question-- using a tag at minimum-- what your RDBMS is. It's not too late. But what you link to in your question seems to accept the solution I wrote, so it seems there's more than one disconnect in how you're posing your question.